# Three.js how to control json animation?

Tags: json, animation, model, 3d, three.js

I loaded a json animation from blender using this code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'monster2.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = materials[ 0 ];
        material.morphTargets = true;
        material.color.setHex( 0xffaaaa );
        meshFace = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
        morph = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry, meshFace );
        morph.duration = 1000;
        morph.time = 1000 * Math.random();
        morph.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        morph.updateMatrix();
        morph.position.x =0;
        morph.position.y =0;
        morph.position.z =0;
        morph.scale.set(100,100,100);
        scene.add( morph );
    });
```

is it possible to animate my "morph" like an array? If i want a specific frame to be shown, can i just somehow do something like this: morph[5] ?

I am trying to accomplish a simple animation control for walking, standing etc.

If my question does not make sense (which I feel like it doesn't), then how would I accomplish animation control? I don't need anything fancy, just any kind of simplistic control would totally do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(morph){
            for(var i=0;i<morph.morphTargetInfluences.length;i++){
                morph.morphTargetInfluences[i]=0;
            }
            morph.morphTargetInfluences[SOME_INTEGER_HERE]=1;   
    }
```

This works. The problem was that 'SOME_INTEGER_HERE' was not an integer, it was, a string, i guess.